# PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out' when trying to connect to google cloud sql

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Hie members
so I was trying to connect to Google cloud sql from an external site

I authorized the ip of the server in google cloud at Instance -> Access Control -> Authorization

and the instance also has been assigned an IP lets say 'X.X.X.X',
and a user also has been created with User name 'username' and password 'password'

now the connection code for connecting google cloud sql I used is as follows

```
$db = new pdo('mysql:host=X.X.X.X;dbname=db','username','password');
```

and I tried opening the page and I am getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out' in /home/kannadakavana/public_html/test.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /home/kannadakavana/public_html/test.php(17): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=X....', 'username', '') #1 {main} thrown in /home/kannadakavana/public_html/test.php on line 17
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I tried authorizing my local system ip and ran the script and it works !!!
so the problem here is actually the firewall
Thanks guys for your support :)

Comment: How you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

By default Cloud SQL instances does not have IPv4 enable.

Did you enable IPv4 address? It is under Access Control > IP address tab.

Comment: yes sir
I did enable IPV4 address and I'm using it as `mysql:host="assigned ip"`  
am I doing it right?

Comment: do we have to give any port number ?

Comment: It uses the default MySQL port number - you shouldn't need to do that.

When you said `mysql:host="assigned ip"`, I'm assuming that it is something like `mysql:host="10.0.0.1"` (another valid IP address).

Can you connect using the command line mysql?

Comment: actually the problem was solved
I authorized with local ip of my system which worked !!
and it was the firewall of my server that did not let the server to connect to cloud sql
Thanks for your support anyway sir :)

Answer (score 0):

If the CloudSQL instance is an on-demand instance, you will sometime get a connection timeout on first attempt as the instance spins up.

If that is the problem then the solution is either an always on instance or (preferably) an automated connection retry with back-off.

Comment: sorry sir I did not get this part `an automated connection retry with back-off` and if it means reloading the page, I did try reloading the page every 5 min for an hour