# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: with Google Cloud SQL Instance Connection

Tags: php, pdo

I have created a `Google Cloud SQL Instance` but I cannot figure out how to connect with it through `php`. I am not able to connect to my Cloud Instance through `PDO` or `mysqli_connect` in a `php` file stored on a local `Xampp Server`. Please Help I keep on receiving a error. I'm struggling a lot. I have given some details below, if more are required please let me know.

Database Name: `test_database`.

Instance User: `test_user` & `pass`.

---

`Google Cloud SQL Instance Info:`

Public IP address: `35.244.68.115`

Instance connection name: `test-244508:australia-southeast1:test`

---

`test.php:`

```
<?php
    $dsn = "mysql:host=35.244.68.115;dbname=test_database;unix_socket=/cloudsql/test-244508:australia-southeast1:test";
    $user = "test_user";
    $password = "pass";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    // OR

    $mysqli_conn = mysqli_connect("35.244.68.115", "test_user", "pass", "test_database");
?>
```

---

`error:`

`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php(19): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=35.2...', 'test_user', 'pass') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 19`

Comment: Don't picture text please.

Comment: @dr0i there I have updated the question. please help me

Comment: Good. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581543/unable-to-access-google-cloud-sql-from-gae-sqlstatehy000-2002-unknown-erro , have you followed the advices? Don't use password, following https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/ ?

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522035/pdoexception-with-message-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-timed-out-when-tr?rq=1.